# How can I call what() after throwing an unhandled, custom exception?

Tags: c++, debugging, exception, custom-exceptions

When you throw and unhandled `std::runtime_error`, the terminal automatically prints the result of `what()` making debugging a lot easier. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    throw std::runtime_error("This is an error message.\n");
}
```

Console output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  This is an error message.
```

Custom exception classes derived by this class show the same behaviour, exception classes made from scratch don't do that by default.

But the exception class I want to create must not be derived from `std::runtime_error`.. And for debugging purposes, `what()` should still be printed after the program crashs - but I can't figure out how to do that no matter what! Can someone help me please?

At the moment, it looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Custom_Exception
{
    std::string Msg;

    Custom_Exception(std::string Error_Msg) noexcept
    {
        Msg=Error_Msg;
    }

    std::string what() noexcept
    {
        return Msg;
    }
};

int main()
{
    throw Custom_Exception("This is an error message.\n");
}
```

Console output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Custom_Exception'
```

No `what():` in the error message... Putting a `std::cout<<Msg;` into the destructor doesn't help either.

Please help me with your suggestions! Thank you.

Comment: "But the exception class I want to create must not be derived from std::runtime_error." - Why not?

Comment: Catch your exceptions in main and do what you want with them.  I wouldn't rely on the runtime to do this for you.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It forces me to use certain data types or to convert them every time, it prevents me from creating a generic exception class which I want to use for my own projects, I want to know how to add this feature for the sake of curiosity. I just don't like it that way. Otherwise I could just use std::runtime_error itself... But I want by custom exception class because it can certain things std::runtime_error can't.

Comment: @Thynome _"But I want by custom exception class because it can certain things std::runtime_error can't."_ Could you elaborate about this please?

Comment: I do not recommend a generic exception class.

Comment: `what()` is virtual. You can (and should) derive custom exceptions from `std::runtime_error` (or any other appropriate [`std::exception`-based class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception)) and override `what()` to say whatever you want.  The only thing you are limited to is returning a `char*`, but you can format that using whatever data types you want.  So derive a custom exception where you pass the desired data types to its constructor, and then have the constructor format the error message into a `std::string` as needed, and let `what()` return that message.

Comment: @Thynome what you call tedious I call standard practice.

Answer (score 4):

The minimum exception interface to use `what()` with the [`std::terminate_handler`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler) is [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception):

```
struct Custom_Exception : public std::exception {
    std::string Msg;
public:
    Custom_Exception(std::string Error_Msg) noexcept : Msg(Error_Msg) {
    }

    const char* what() const { return Msg.c_str(); }
};
```

---

Another option without inheriting from the `std::exception` interface is to catch your custom exceptions in `main()`

```
int main()
{
    try {
        throw Custom_Exception("This is an error message.\n");
    }
    catch(const Custom_Exception& ce) {
        std::cerr << ce.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

or override and set the `std::terminate_handler` with your own handler.

Comment: Can you explain how to properly override `std::terminate_handler` and how I can integrate it into my exception class please?

Comment: @Thynome I'm not finally sure if a `std::terminate_handler` override function may rethrow and catch like `try { throw; } catch(const Custom_Exception& ce)  { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: You can. [except.handle]/7 says that *an implicit handler
is considered active when std::terminate()[...] is entered due to a throw*, so you can safely rethrow exception from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should derive your exception from std::exception which offers a virtual destructor and the virtual what() method. If you override the destructor you should be able to print your message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class Custom_Exception : std::exception
{
    char const* Msg;

    Custom_Exception(char const* Error_Msg) noexcept
    {
        Msg=Error_Msg;
    }

    Custom_Exception(Custom_Exception const& other)
    {
        Msg = other.Msg;
    }

    Custom_Exception& operator=(Custom_Exception const& other)
    {
        Msg = other.Msg;
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~Custom_Exception()
    {
    }

    virtual char const* what() const noexcept
    {
        return Msg;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try 
    {
      throw Custom_Exception("This is an error message.\n");
    }
    catch (Custom_Exception& ex)
    {
      std::cout << "what(): " << ex.what();
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this print the error message even if the exception is never thrown? And also even if it's caught?

Comment: Oh, yes. Whenever the exception is destructed. So πάντα ῥεῖ's answer with the outer catch might work.

Comment: It is not the destructor's responsibility to output the error message. That is why `what()` exists, to return the error message when it is needed.